# Convert a Pandas Dataframe to specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'UNIQUE_KEY': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'TRANSFORMATION': ['P', 'D', 'N', 'P'], 
     'DIM_1': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 'DIM_2': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 'DIM_3': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']})


    UNIQUE_KEY  TRANSFORMATION  DIM_1   DIM_2   DIM_3
0   1           P               Y       N       Y
1   2           D               N       N       Y
2   3           N               N       N       N
3   4           P               Y       Y       Y
```

I want to perform several `groupby` and aggregate operations in order to get the following output dataframe:

```
    DIM      DIM_VALUE   TTL_CASES   % CASES   % D    % N    % P 
0   DIM_1    'Y'         2           50        0      0      100
1   DIM_1    'N'         2           50        50     50     0
2   DIM_2    'Y'         1           25        0      0      100
3   DIM_2    'N'         3           75        33.3   33.3   33.3
4   DIM_3    'Y'         3           75        33.3   0      66.6
5   DIM_3    'N'         1           25        0      100    0
```

Where

- `DIM` is a column with each of `DIM_1,2,3`
- `DIM_VALUE` is a grouped column based on the values of each `DIM_1,2,3`
- `TTL_CASES` is a column with the count of `UNIQUE_KEY` grouped by `DIM` and `DIM_1,2,3`
- `PCT_CASES` is the percentage of each row of `TTL_CASES`
- `%D`, `%P`, `%N` are the percentages of `TRANSFORMATION` of `UNIQUE_KEY` based on the the grouped by `DIM` and `DIM_1,2,3`

What I have is the following:

```
P = d.groupby('TRANSFORMATION')['UNIQUE_KEY'].count().reset_index()
P['Percentage'] = 100 * P['UNIQUE_KEY']  / P['UNIQUE_KEY'].sum()
```

which gives me the percentage of each value in `TRANFORMATION` but how do I do this for each dimension and get an output dataframe in the format I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is no easy way to achieve the desired output, you need to break the problem down into multiple steps: First melt the dataframe to convert DIM like columns to rows, then create two grouper objects, calculate the aggregations using the grouper objects as required and assign the results to output dataframe

```py
s = d.melt(['UNIQUE_KEY', 'TRANSFORMATION'], var_name='DIM', value_name='DIM_VALUE')

g1 = s.groupby(['DIM'])
g2 = s.groupby(['DIM', 'DIM_VALUE'])

out = pd.DataFrame()
out['TTL_CASES'] = g2['UNIQUE_KEY'].count()
out['%_TTL_CASES'] = out['TTL_CASES'].div(g1['UNIQUE_KEY'].count()).mul(100)
out = out.assign(**g2['TRANSFORMATION'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('%'))
```

Result

```
     DIM DIM_VALUE  TTL_CASES  %_TTL_CASES         %D          %N          %P
0  DIM_1         N          2         50.0  50.000000   50.000000    0.000000
1  DIM_1         Y          2         50.0   0.000000    0.000000  100.000000
2  DIM_2         N          3         75.0  33.333333   33.333333   33.333333
3  DIM_2         Y          1         25.0   0.000000    0.000000  100.000000
4  DIM_3         N          1         25.0   0.000000  100.000000    0.000000
5  DIM_3         Y          3         75.0  33.333333    0.000000   66.666667
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this `.melt` method. The last line of your code is also really cool! Thanks for sharing the nice technique. Upvoted.

Comment: Very sophisticated and concise solution! Can you explain briefly what is happening in the last line of the code?

Comment: @MOA In the last line, first we are creating a normalized frequency table using `groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack` then we are assigning/creating the columns into output dataframe using the columns from frequency table. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma what do the `**` mean?

Comment: @MOA `**` is used for unpacking operation. So basically it unpacks the columns from frequency table and assigns them to output dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'UNIQUE_KEY': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'TRANSFORMATION': ['P', 'D', 'N', 'P'], 'DIM_1': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 'DIM_2': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 'DIM_3': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y']})

# Transform df shape
df = df.set_index(['UNIQUE_KEY', 'TRANSFORMATION']).stack().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['UNIQUE_KEY', 'TRANSFORMATION', 'DIM', 'DIM_VALUE']

# Get aggregated values except PCT_CASES
df = df.groupby(['DIM', 'DIM_VALUE'], as_index=False).agg(
    TTL_CASES=pd.NamedAgg('UNIQUE_KEY', 'count'),
    PCT_D=pd.NamedAgg('TRANSFORMATION', lambda s: 100 * (s=='D').sum() / len(s)),
    PCT_N=pd.NamedAgg('TRANSFORMATION', lambda s: 100 * (s=='N').sum() / len(s)),
    PCT_P=pd.NamedAgg('TRANSFORMATION', lambda s: 100 * (s=='P').sum() / len(s)),
).sort_values(['DIM', 'DIM_VALUE'], ascending=[True, False])

# Add PCT_CASES
df.insert(3, 'PCT_CASES', df.groupby('DIM')['TTL_CASES'].transform(lambda s: 100 * s / s.sum()))
```

### Output:

| DIM | DIM_VALUE | TTL_CASES | PCT_CASES | PCT_D | PCT_N | PCT_P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DIM_1 | Y | 2 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| DIM_1 | N | 2 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 0 |
| DIM_2 | Y | 1 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| DIM_2 | N | 3 | 75 | 33.3333 | 33.3333 | 33.3333 |
| DIM_3 | Y | 3 | 75 | 33.3333 | 0 | 66.6667 |
| DIM_3 | N | 1 | 25 | 0 | 100 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you for the response! For some reason I get an error with NamedAgg (`module 'pandas' has no attribute 'NamedAgg' `) but I understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind message. As for `pd.NamedAgg`, Pandas 0.25+ is actually needed.